# Display a larger image from a mysql database using a mouseover effect

Tags: javascript, php

I have created a simple mysql database which holds links to two images - a thumbnail (thumb_image) and a larger image (large_image).  I can get the thumbnail to appear with a title tag using the following code:

```
...echo "<td>";?> <img src="<?php echo $row['thumb_image']; ?>" height="100" width="125" title="<?php echo $row['title_tag']; ?>"  /><?php echo "</td>";...
```

How could I make sure the larger image would only appear when a user mouses over the thumbnail?

Thanks,

Andy ;-)

Comment: PHP runs on the server. Not in the browser. Once your data is in the browser, and it's being turned into a visible page, PHP is no longer involved. So, if you want to do something based on user interaction on the page, make the browser receive HTML, CSS and JS that will make that happen.

Comment: I have updated my answer for you below. This should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the onmouseover function below, you can change the src of the image itself. The you would have to add the onmouseout to turn it back.

```
...echo "<td>";?>
<img onmouseover="this.src=<?php echo "'" . $row['full_image'] . "'"; ?>;" onmouseout="this.src=<?php echo "'" . $row['thumb_image'] . "'"; ?>;" src="<?php echo $row['thumb_image']; ?>" height="100" width="125" title="<?php echo $row['title_tag']; ?>"  />
<?php echo "</td>";...
```

Comment: Hi Denver, just tried it and thanks for the solution, worked a treat, Andy ;-)

Comment: The please accept the answer, that is what this site is all about, letting people know via that check mark that the answer works.